# A simple calculator to calculate the frequency of a recessive allele

Tags: python

It's based on the [Hardy-Weinberg formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle). I used the easygui module because I don't fully understand events in Tkinter yet. It's my first relatively useful script so any constructive criticism would be helpful.

```
from __future__ import division
import sys
from easygui import *
def calculate_frequency(recessive,total):
    q = (recessive/total)**0.5 #square root of q^2
    p = 1-q #since p + q = 1, p = 1-q
    hzDominantNum = round((p**2)*total,2) #number of homozygous dominant, not percent
    hzRecessiveNum = round((q**2)*total,2)
    heterozygousNum = round((2*p*q)*total,2)
    hzDominantFreq = round((p**2)*100,2) #frequency (percent)
    hzRecessiveFreq = round((q**2)*100,2)
    heterozygousFreq = round((2*p*q)*100,2)
    return hzDominantNum,hzRecessiveNum,heterozygousNum,hzDominantFreq,hzRecessiveFreq,heterozygousFreq #returns all calculations to be printed
while True: #loops program until terminated
    msg = "Leave Total as 100 if you want to enter the percent." #main message lets user know how to input as percent
    fieldNames = ["How many have the recessive trait","Total population"]
    fieldValues = ['',100] #first one is blank, the second is defaulted to 100 to make inputing percents easier
    test = 0 #tests if the proper information has been entered. Test will equal 1 if the conditions are met.
    while test == 0:
        fieldValues = multenterbox(msg=msg, title='Enter information about the population', fields=fieldNames, values=fieldValues)
        if fieldValues == None: sys.exit() #None is returned when the user clicks "Cancel"
        elif not fieldValues[0].isdigit() or not fieldValues[1].isdigit():
            if not ccbox("Please fill out all fields.",'ERROR',('OK','Quit')): sys.exit()
        elif int(fieldValues[0])>int(fieldValues[1]):
            if not ccbox("The amount of people with the recessive trait can't be bigger than the total population.",'ERROR',('OK','Quit')): sys.exit()
        else: test=1
    recessive = int(fieldValues[0])
    total = int(fieldValues[1])

    hzDominantNum,hzRecessiveNum,heterozygousNum,hzDominantFreq,hzRecessiveFreq,heterozygousFreq = calculate_frequency(recessive,total)
    #displays all the information
    msg = str(hzDominantNum)+'/'+str(total)+' ('+str(hzDominantFreq)+'%) are normal (homozygous dominant).\n'+'''
    '''+str(heterozygousNum)+'/'+str(total)+' ('+str(heterozygousFreq)+'%) are carriers (heterozygous).\n'+'''
    '''+str(hzRecessiveNum)+'/'+str(total)+' ('+str(hzRecessiveFreq)+'%) have the recessive trait (homozygous recessive).'
    #sees if user wants to quit or continue
    if not ccbox(msg=msg, title='RESULTS', choices=('Continue', 'Quit'), image=None): sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- call variables `this_way` not `thisWay`
- use less comments
- put your interaction with user into separate functions
- if code will be splited properly you will be able to user `return` and `while True:` instead of `test` variable
- return object or dict from `calculate_frequency` rather than long tuple
- don't create strings like that:

  str(hzDominantNum)+'/'+str(total)+' ('+str(hzDominantFreq)+'%) are normal (homozygous dominant).\n'

this is mutch better:

```
'%f/%f (%d%%) are normal (homozygous dominant).\n' % (hzDominantNum, total, hzDominantFreq)
```

if you have to run this as a program do it this way:

```
def main():
    print "test"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Good advice. What exactly is the purpose of adding a main loop if I want to run it as a program?

Comment: that's not a main _loop_, but the `if __name__ == "__main__":` entrypoint is used so that you can _also_ reuse `module.calculate_frequency` from another file later if you want to; this also makes it much easier to write unit tests

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace!
`1 + 1` and not `1+1`
`value, value` and not `value,value`

Blank lines after imports, loops, function definitions and after five lines of code without (just kidding about the latter)

Break your lines if they're getting too long (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

And generally have a look at PEP8